# (how) can you train a model twice (multiple times) in sklearn using fit.?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Example : my data doesn't fit into memory can I do :

```
model=my_model
for i in range(20)
       model.fit(X_i,Y_i)
```

This will delete the first 19 fit. and keep only the last one.
How can I avoid this? Can I retrain a model saved and loaded?
Thank you

Comment: Depending on what kind of data you're working with, creating a sparse matrix might be a viable solution: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html For me this has made the difference between having to fit on an instance with "a lot" of RAM (~16gb+) and being able to fit on my laptop with 4GB of RAM. You'll also have to plan ahead and see which models support sparse input (not all do)

Answer (score 8):

Some models have a "warm_start" parameter, where it will initialise model parameters with the previous solution from fit()

See for instance [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html)

Answer (score 7):

You need to read 6.1.3. Incremental learning from sklearn documentation http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html

Comment: are there no other solution? I already saw the documentation but I need another algorithm that is not listed (ICA)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to reduce your data first, either extract a subset of your data, or reduce the dimensions of your data with the help of a database. This would significantly reduce the amount of your data.

You may want to create multiple models from randomly picked subsets of your data, and then compare the models, and use the best model that yields the highest accuracy.